# Terminology for ponding behind a bridge during a flood

Tags: civil-engineering, hydrology

I have read a specific term to describe the process when water pools behind a restriction such as a bridge during a flood. I cannot for the life of me remember what the word was.

The term specifically refers to the process of the ponding of water upstream of a restriction during a flood creating an area where the water pools higher and velocity is slower. Essentially the flood version of localised water detention due to a outlet restriction.

If anyone could help me out with the exact terminology that would be great. Have been searching all over to no avail.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that the phrase that you are looking for is either **backwater** or **headwater**.

[image]
<sub>Image from from http://epg.modot.org/index.php?title=748.4_Headwater_and_Backwater</sub>